# Can Someone please explain in detail how i do this formula in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to create a single page app where I want to add and multiply some values, values are given below;

(currentTime.Day + currentTime.Month + 39) * currentTime.Year

and i want the value shown below and also get copied

this is the formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA6rf.png)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: try explaining your question in detail, there is not enough context to understand what your trying to achieve.

Comment: actually I need a value to be shown when I open the app. the value must be the answer of this (current date + current Month + 39) * current Year). the date, month and year must be fixed as of the phone they are using. how will i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the formula using dart's date time class methods.
Use the below code to get for the formula.

```
void main() {
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();
print((currentTime.day + currentTime.month + 39) * 
currentTime.year); 
}
```

Reading the above comments you also want to copy the result of the expression.

You can use the **SelectableText** widget to solve that problem or you can use the above mentioned **Clipboard** service by importing the flutter/services.dart

You can view the working example of my code on dartpad [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=f9cbd73473edd39e942355df2dfe3342)

To copy the value you just have to long press on the text and it will give you the option to copy the text.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(
MaterialApp(
  home: const CalculatorExpression(),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
  ),
 );
}

class CalculatorExpression extends StatefulWidget {
const CalculatorExpression({super.key});

@override
State<CalculatorExpression> createState() => 
_CalculatorExpressionState();
}

class _CalculatorExpressionState extends 
 State<CalculatorExpression> {
  String buttonText = '';
  int? day;
  int? month;
  int? year;
@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
  day = DateTime.now().day;
  month = DateTime.now().month;
  year = DateTime.now().year;

  buttonText = ((day! + month! + 39) * year!).toString();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: const Text('Date Time Expression'),
  ),
  body: Center(   
    child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
    children: [ Text("The expression 
      (($day + $month + 39) * $year) will result to give the 
      below value:"),SelectableText(buttonText),]) 
     ),
    );
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understood you want this fuzzy expression to be implemented, you can refer the below code:

```
void main() {
  int day = DateTime.now().day;
  int month = DateTime.now().month;
  int year = DateTime.now().year;

  int result = (day + month + 39) * year;

  print(result);
}
```

For adding this data to your device clipboard you need a button, on it's click it will add the value to the clipboard:

import this `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

And then Simply implement this into your onPressed of the button:

```
onPressed: () async {
  await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: result));
  // copied successfully
},
```

Replace this below code with your main file code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: const Home(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
    ),
  );
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late String buttonText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    int day = DateTime.now().day;
    int month = DateTime.now().month;
    int year = DateTime.now().year;

    buttonText = ((day + month + 39) * year).toString();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Copy to Clipboard'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(buttonText),
          onPressed: () async {
            await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: buttonText.toString()));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i implement this code in a page in my app?

Comment: just calculate this on the screen you need.

Comment: how can the value be shown in the screen in a way it can be copied?

Comment: i have edited the answer, let me know if you need any other help

Comment: why is it showing still error on onpressed?

Comment: add your whole code in the question, so i can assist you..! Or your can follow this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-add-copy-to-clipboard-without-package/ remove the text field and add my void main code in the button click itself and then the  `Clipboard.setData`thing.

Comment: i cant add the code, i will add the screenshot above please check

Comment: the only error i am having is the result part on on pressed. it is showing like this: lib/main.dart:49:59: Error: The getter 'result' isn't defined for the class 'HomePage'.
 - 'HomePage' is from 'package:demo/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'result'.
              await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: result));
                                                          ^^^^^^

Comment: Bro the whole code is wrong. i'm updating my answer take the last code snippet and replace with your whole main file code.

Comment: hey, i have given the exact code you said, but the value isn't shown. it just shows copy, i have added the screenshot above

Comment: instead of text copy i want the value to be shown there, how can i do it?

Comment: i have updated the code, take that and replace it with the pervious one.

Comment: they are showing button text has not been initialized

Comment: It's working for me, Add some screenshot in your question.